# Can Xbox One and Xbox One S consoles play together?

Tags: xbox-one

If I have a Xbox one S and my friend has an Xbox One, can we play together on online games? GTA, COD, etc

Comment: Have you tried? What makes you think that you can't?

Comment: He hasn’t bought one yet. He’s still on the 360. He doesn’t know to get the S or the regular one.

Comment: Get witch one you want. All Xbox Ones work thoghther (basic, S, X)

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely they can, they operate off the same generation, so they're more or less the same. Like the Iphone 6 and 6s. Ones just a tad different.

Comment: This obviously also extends to the xbox one X as well - equally compatible with the basic and the S.